# Dynamic height and width of src attribute in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

I am trying to fit some src URL in iframe tag. To fit its content in my application I'm using the iframe tag. To fit and give a proper look and feel in the application I'm trying to give dynamic width and height to iframe based on contents of src.

Following is the code:

```
<iframe id="ifrm" src="https://some-url" onload="setIframeHeight(this.id)"></iframe>

function getDocHeight(doc) {
    doc = doc || document;
    // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
    var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    return height;
}

function setIframeHeight(id) {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
    var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: 
        ifrm.contentWindow.document;
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ifrm.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height ...
    // IE opt. for bing/msn needs a bit added or scrollbar appears
    ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 4 + "px";
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Here function getDocHeight is returning 0. So I'm getting 4px has height to iframe.

So how can I achieve to get height based on content of src url ?

Comment: is the `https://some-url` cross domain? If so, you may not be able to get content height of an external url unless there is a supportive CORS policy in place - In that case, set an approximate height that you see.

Comment: What would be the supportive CORS policy for height?